MacOS: AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'
I kept getting this error:
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'

I tried to follow solutions from this stackoverflow question, however still getting the same error.
If I comment out everything else, and just execute:
import socket
print(socket)

It returns this, which looks good to me,
<module 'socket' from '/Users/raheyo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/socket.py'>

However, when I try printing the constants:
print(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH)

I get the same error again for "no attribute 'AF_BLUETOOTH'"
Note that it doesn't just happen for 'AF_BLUETOOTH', same thing happens for 'AF_ASH' and 'AF_ALG'.
Please help!

AF_BLUETOOTH is not available on all platforms

What @SIGHUP said, however, official docs do not mention platforms where AF_BLUETOOTH is supported but pretty safe to safe its not on MacOS. Also, AF_ALG is explicitly said to be supported only on Linux with new enough kernel and AF_ASH is not mentioned in the docs at all AF_ASH

So what should I do if I still want to use Bluetooth connection?
